# AngularJs - Problemas com acentuação

Tags: angularjs, servlet, encode

Estou recebendo strings na `servlet` com problemas na acentuação.
Como por exemplo: 
Enviar `$scope.nome = "Pé"` para a `servlet`.
Na `servlet` a linha: `String nome = request.getParameter("nome");` não recebe `Pé` e sim `PÃc`

Arquivo `js` faço a requisição:

```
var ajaxApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

ajaxApp.controller("gridUsersControl", [ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";

    $scope.saveUser = function() {

        var data = {
            'action'    : 'saveUser',
            'id'        : $scope.id,
            'nome'      : $scope.nome,
            'sobrenome' : $scope.sobrenome,
            'email'     : $scope.email,
            'telefone'  : $scope.telefone,
            'rua'       : $scope.rua,
            'bairro'        : $scope.bairro,
            'cidade'        : $scope.cidade,
            'estado'        : $scope.estado,
        }

        $http({
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url : 'UserController',
            method : "POST",
            params: data,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}

        }).then(function(response) {

            $('#dialogEditUser').modal('hide');
            generalDialog('Usuário cadastrado com sucesso.');
            console.log(response.data);
            angular.element(document.getElementById('principalUsers')).scope().loadUsers();


        }, function(response) {
            generalDialog('Problemas ao cadastrar usuário.');
            console.log(response);
        });
    };
} ]);
```

Minha Servlet:

```
public class UserController extends HttpServlet{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        doPost(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        String action = request.getParameter("action");

        switch(action){

            case "saveUser":
                saveUser(request, response);
        }   
    }

    private void saveUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        String id = request.getParameter("id");
        String nome = request.getParameter("nome");
        String sobrenome = request.getParameter("sobrenome");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String telefone = request.getParameter("telefone");
        String rua = request.getParameter("rua");
        String bairro = request.getParameter("bairro");
        String cidade = request.getParameter("cidade");
        String estado = request.getParameter("estado");

        Usuario user = null;

        if(id != null){
            user = (Usuario) PersistEngine.findById(Usuario.class, Integer.valueOf(id));
        } else {    
            user = new Usuario();
        }

        user.setNome(nome);
        user.setSobrenome(sobrenome);
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setTelefone(telefone);
        user.setRua(rua);
        user.setBairro(bairro);
        user.setCidade(cidade);
        user.setEstado(estado);
        PersistEngine.persist(user);
    }
}
```

Cabeçalho do arquivo `Jsp` com meta `tag`:

```
"<"meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Alguém sabe como eu poderia resolver?

Comment: Quando eu tive problema com isso, a questão era no meu servidor. Tive que mudar o UTC dentro do servidor para poder receber/enviar os caracteres corretamente. Não sei como seria no seu caso, mas quem sabe ajuda de alguma maneira

Answer (score 1):

Não estou usando uma Servlet diretamente, mas vou lhe passar as configurações que estou utilizando. Talvez isso te ajude.

- prelude.jspf

  ```
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
  ```
- index.jsp

  ```
  <!doctype html>
  <html lang="pt-br">
      <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
  ```